# Binning a continuous feature for a SVM

Tags: svm, binning

I am using a support vector machine (SVM) for binary classification.  One of my features is continuous: each item has an attribute $x$ that is a real number.  For various reasons (e.g., because I suspect the relationship between $x$ and the class of the item is not a simple linear relationship), I suspect the SVM will be more effective if I first bin $x$ into one of a few bins, so it becomes categorical.

Is there a method of binning that works best for SVMs?  Is the performance of the SVM sensitive to the choice of binning method?  For instance, consider the following two options:

- Option A: Introduce five zero-or-one features $y_1,\dots,y_5$ corresponding to five bins, where $y_1=1$ if $x$ is in the low 20% percentile of range of values, $y_2=1$ if $x$ is in the 20-40% percentile, $y_3=1$ if $x$ is in the 40-60% percentile, etc.
- Option B: Introduce five zero-or-one features $y_1,\dots,y_5$ corresponding to five bins, where $y_1=1$ if $x$ is in the low 20% percentile of range of values, $y_2=1$ if $x$ is in the low 40% percentile, $y_3=1$ if $x$ is in the low 60% percentile, etc.

(Thus Option A is more like an estimate of the pdf, and Option B is more like an estimate of the cdf.)

Does one of these two options tend to work better with SVMs?

For instance, I'm thinking that Option B might interact better with regularization (and parsimony).  For instance, if just testing whether $x$ is in its low 60% is enough to get most of the predictive power out of $x$, then with Option B the SVM might put weight on $y_3$ and not any of the other $y_i$'s (with the corresponding regularization bonus), whereas Option A has no similar sparse option available to it.  But I'm speculating wildly.  Does it make a difference, in practice, and if so, how should I choose what binning method to use?

Comment: Any predictive or classification method that requires binning of continuous variables has a problem.  And note that percentiles have nothing to do with true inflection points on effect curves.  They are arbitrarily manipulated by sampling.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, I do understand, and I appreciate the value of that perspective... (and I did read a bunch of other questions here about binning)... but, to be honest, that doesn't really help me.  Taking into account all the other features, a SVM performs better on my task than other alternatives.  This question is about how to incorporate a continuous-valued feature into a SVM.  I don't really want to get into a debate over whether SVM's are a good or useful machine learning method.  All machine learning methods have problems, but some are useful nonetheless.

Comment: Have you considered trying different kernels (e.g. polynomial)?

Comment: I've not used SVM but for many other methods you can easily relax linearity assumptions using cubic spline functions.  Note that when you say "performing better" you are using a proper accuracy score (e.g., Brier score or mean squared error).

Comment: No, I hadn't considered other kernels.  Thank you for the suggestion, @Chaconne!  Frank Harrell, do you know how to use cubic splines with SVM?  For measuring performance, I've simply been using cross-validation. I'm not seeing what mean squared error has to do with this question, and I'm not familiar with Brier score.  This is a binary classification task, not a regression task.

Comment: SVM is a classification technique that is centrally based on a vector space - and so converting from continuous to categorical is a bad move. If you use a RBF kernel, the separating surfaces are NOT linear, and the SVM may find the best surface that will separate the classes.